# Saving Hashed Version of User Password in Django Form Not Working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have been trying to save the hashed version of a user password but it's not working.

**forms.py**:

```
class up_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields =['email', 'password', 'username', 'status']
```

**views.py**:

```
from myapp.forms import up_form
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sign_up = up_form(request.POST or None)
        if sign_up.is_valid():
            sign_up.password = make_password(sign_up.cleaned_data['password'])
            sign_up = sign_up.save(commit = False)
            sign_up.status = 1
            sign_up.save()
```

But my `password` still get saved in plain text. How do I come around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to switch the order of your statements, because you have named the object as the same name as the form itself.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    sign_up = up_form(request.POST)
    if sign_up.is_valid():
        sign_up = sign_up.save(commit = False)
        sign_up.password = make_password(sign_up.cleaned_data['password'])
```

I hope you are also returning a response from the method, and redirecting users appropriately after the POST request.

Consider this version:

```
def register(request):
    form = up_form(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        sign_up = form.save(commit=False)
        sign_up.password = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
        sign_up.status = 1
        sign_up.save()
        return redirect('/thank-you/')
    return render(request, 'sign_up_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: This returns `AttributeError at /myapp/register/
'Users' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'`.

Comment: Sorry about that, try it now.

Answer (score 6):

The best way would be to follow what Django's original [UserCreationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/#UserCreationForm) does and override your form's `save` method:

```
class UpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields =['email', 'password', 'username', 'status']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

This way you don't have to `make_password()` in every view you use your form.

Comment: why not just subclass UserCreationForm?

Comment: OP didn't say he was creating a user. I'm just recommending to leave the processing to the form class instead of nesting if-statements in the view.