# I get an error list that says this field is required

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

this is the forms page

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Profile
        fields = ['pic']
```

& this is the views page

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserForm, ProfileForm

def register(request):
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        userform = UserForm(request.POST)
        profileform = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if(userform.is_valid() and profileform.is_valid()):
            user = userform.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profileform.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            if('pic' in request.FILES):
                profile.pic = request.FILES['pic']
            profile.save()
        else:
            print(userform.errors, profileform.errors)
    else:
        userform = UserForm()
        profileform = ProfileForm()

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'userform':userform,
                                             'profileform':profileform})
```

when I submit the password or the picture it doesn't save the user to the admin area and says that password is required and the picture is not uploaded

Comment: Can you show `register.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `commit=False` when saving password from the form and not like in ordinary form with using `set()`.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

    class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)
        class Meta:
            model = Users
            fields =['email', 'password', 'username']

    class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta():
            model = Profile
            fields = ['pic']
```

---

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserForm, ProfileForm

def register(request):
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
        profileform = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)
        if(userform.is_valid() and profileform.is_valid()):
            userform = form.save(commit=False)
            userform.password = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            userform.save()

            profile = profileform.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            if('pic' in request.FILES):
                profile.pic = request.FILES['pic']
            profile.save()
        else:
            print(userform.errors, profileform.errors)
    else:
        userform = UserForm()
        profileform = ProfileForm()

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'userform':userform,
                                             'profileform':profileform})
```

Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112779/saving-hashed-version-of-user-password-in-django-form-not-working) also.